# Прогнозирование временных рядов SARIMAX statsmodels в Python

Tags: python, математика

Для прогнозирования временного ряда я использую модель SARIMAX. Строю модель, сохраняю рассчитанные коэффициенты и пытаюсь применить на новом множестве. Я считаю, что предобученная модель SARIMAX с параметрами `order=(1, 1, 1)`, `seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 1)` для прогнозирования должна использовать 5 последних значений ряда. Однако пример ниже показывает, что она использует более 50 исторических значений для прогноза. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так?

Пример

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

X = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 9.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 3.0, 7.0, 11.0, 17.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0, 16.0, 17.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 9.0, 18.0, 24.0, 7.0, 7.0, 6.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 3.0, 7.0, 11.0, 17.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0, 16.0, 17.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 9.0, 18.0, 24.0, 7.0, 7.0, 6.0]

train = X[:-1]
model = SARIMAX(train, order=(1, 1, 1), seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 1))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
modelB = SARIMAX(train[-50:], order=(1, 1, 1), seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 1))
resB = modelB.smooth(model_fit.params)
y = model_fit.forecast()
y2 = resB.forecast()

print(y, y2)
```

Результат `y = 8.34461063`, `y2 = 8.19208365`. Я ожидала, что `y == y2`, но это не так. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему?

P.S. Я знаю, что проблема в расчете скользящей средней. Т.е. модель с параметрами `order=(1, 1, 0)`, `seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 1)` для прогноза будет использовать 4 последних значения ряда. А исходная модель (см. пример) почему-то требует более 50 одинаковых значений на хвосте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

модель зависит не только от коэффициентов модели SARIMA, но и от шума epsilon_t.  Хотя формально каждый член ряда зависит от шума 4-х предыдущих членов ряда, шум четырех предыдущих высчитывается по ещё предыдущим и так до самого начала. Соответственно у модели есть еще один скрытый параметр - длинна окна для расчета шума.